# Can I do pagination with spring-data-jdbc?

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

I would like to use PagingAndSortingRepository with spring-data-jdbc but it not seem to work. It's only available with JPA ?

I tried to use PagingAndSortingRepository and use the findAll(Pageable pageable).

But I actually get a "No query specified on findAll"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PagingAndSortingRepository` is supported since version 2.0 M3

That version wasn't available when this question was asked.

**Original answer**

Yes, you are right, pagination isn't ready yet.

There is actually a [PR that will create infrastructure](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc/pull/125) for that but it won't enable the feature yet. For that you should watch https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJDBC-101.

Comment: Thank you, is not clear on documentation because the pagination is on the commons part (jpa/jdbc). Or maybe i miss it ?

Comment: yeah, that is rather unfortunate.

Answer (score 5):

**2020 Update**

Support for PagingRepositories was introduced at version 2.0.0.M3 (2020-02-12).

[Spring Data JDBC Changelog](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/changelog.txt)